# Neural networks giving the probability of an element belonging to a particular class

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Which type of neural network is suitable for determining the probability of an element belonging to a particular class?

I've seen examples of neural networks that determine the probabilities of the top class predictions. That is, when I upload a picture of my cat, the neural network determines that this is a cat with a probability of 80%, and that it is a panther of 20%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabilities are a property of the last-stage transformation function, not of the net type.  All you need is that the model solves a classification problem with some evaluation that is well-ordered (e.g. numeric).  Try searching for references to *SoftMax*, a popular transformation.

The critical part is to change the *reporting* of the network's prediction.  For instance, output the top five categories with their confidence percentages (rather than merely the index of the top category).  This is an alteration of the final return value(s).